# some issue with using atom sync-settings tool

Tags: atom-editor

With the risk of me misunderstanding something, I can't get my packages to sync. I went through the following scenario:

1. I install new packages on Machine 1 and upload the settings through the "Sync Backup" command in atom. I can see that the new packages are listed in the packages.json file in the gist.
   On Machine
2. I restore the settings and can indeed see settings being restored, like keymaps. However I don't get my new packages. I have restarted and reloaded Atom without luck.
   Are there any extra steps I need to take to get the new packages on Machine 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [atom-package-sync](https://atom.io/packages/atom-package-sync). It is a package that I created a couple weeks ago. It works a little bit like the synchronization of Google Chrome, you just login and it syncs your packages and settings automatically across all your Atom instances. It is based on package-sync but I find it easier to use.

[image]